# Implement multiple functions in one method

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I am new to solid principle. I think i'm violating this kind of implementation:

```
class Students{
     public void Save(int id){
          if(id !== 0){
               //add students here...
          }else{
               //edit student details here...
          }
     }
}
```

There are many instances that you call different functionalities in one method. Is this right? or if not, please answer sample code. Thank You

Comment: Which principle do you think you're violating?

Comment: Can you give a more elaborate example of what to `Save` method would or should do? `if` statements are not wrong, the only thing that is wrong is that a single function does 2 completely different (and perhaps unexpected) things based on a certain condition. The name of the function should always indicate exactly what the method will do, and return.

Comment: Please insert the complete class as curently it's difficult to see what you are trying to achive. If `Save` is meant to write the current state of the instance, there should be no parameter required. This would make more sense for a create / update method.

Answer (score 1):

There are alot of articles telling what solid does.
Found this one with a quick google.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp

As for you Students class.  It is probably a repository or services to get Students or Save students or to delete student. Only doing stuff around student data. (S(ingle resposibilty))

```
public void Save(Student studentModel)
{
    //Only save the studentModel
}
```

I injected the StudentModel in this function the only thing this function need is this model to do his magic. Refering to the D of(D)ependecy injection.

Please refer the link provided. And try to uphold the SOLID principle. 
Makes your code eventually easier to understand/ maintain. And keep it KISS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle